# tables - siunitx, aligment, column

Tags: tables

I am trying to align the header of this table with no success so far, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, please!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Res.}}  
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}} \\
\midrule
\textbf{1}      & -0.61$\pm$0.32    & 9.1$\times$10$^{7}$\\
\textbf{2}      & -0.37$\pm$0.12    & 2.5$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\textbf{3}      & -0.39$\pm$0.19    & 1.0$\times$10$^{7}$\\
\textbf{4}      & -0.14$\pm$0.13    & 8.0$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\textbf{5}      & -0.10$\pm$0.12    & 2.3$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\textbf{6}      & -0.44$\pm$0.13    & 1.8$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\textbf{7}      & -0.55$\pm$0.16    & 2.0$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\textbf{8a}     & -0.54$\pm$0.16    & 1.9$\times$10$^{6}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[$\beta$ results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV]{The $\beta$ parameter results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV.}
 \label{table:120}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, extend your code sniped to small complete document beginning with `\documentcalss{...}, with necessary packages in preamble and ending with `\end{document}`. Without it is difficult to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I suggest to use `siunitx` package. Using its column type `S` and way to type numbers significantly simplify your table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l 
                            S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                            S[table-format=-1.1e1]
                }  
    \toprule
Res.    & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}    & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}    \\
\midrule
1       & -0.61(32)                 & 9.1e7     \\
2       & -0.37(12)                 & 2.5e6     \\
3       & -0.39(19)                 & 1.0e7     \\
4       & -0.14(13)                 & 8.0e6     \\
5       & -0.10(12)                 & 2.3e6     \\
6       & -0.44(13)                 & 1.8e6     \\
7       & -0.55(16)                 & 2.0e6     \\
8a      & -0.54(16)                 & 1.9e6     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[$\beta$ results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV]{The $\beta$ parameter results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV.}
 \label{table:120}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have wider the second and third columns, then you can prescribe their width similar as you do in `p{...}` type of columns: in `sisetup` add desired width of column as:

```
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-column-width = 22mm}%
```

In this case table become:

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it is perfect! Thanks a million. You are very good at Latex and very kind for sharing!

Comment: well, in the first you accept my answer, now you took-off ... than answer is not so good as you said in your comment above :-(

Comment: Sorry but I am new and I am messing up a bit around here , sorry but your answer is amazing, honestly!  I may have done it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align numbers in a table, use `siunitx`. I suggest you take a look at the documentation, in particular §§ 3.6 and 5.14, *Tabular material*.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand*{\topdblline}{\Xhline{0.15ex}\\[-2.6ex]\hline}
\newcommand*{\botdblline}{\hline\\[-2.6ex]\Xhline{0.15ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
 \centering\sisetup{separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty =2}
  \begin{tabular}{ > {\bfseries}lS[table-format =-1.2(2)]S[table-figures-exponent =1]} \toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{Res.}
&{$ \boldsymbol{\beta} $} & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$} \\%
 \midrule%
  1 & -0.61(32) & 9.1e7\\%
 2 & -0.37(12) & 2.5e6\\%
  3 & -0.39(19) & 1.0e7\\%
 4 & -0.14(13) & 8.0e6\\%
  5 & -0.10(12) & 2.3e6\\%
  6 & -0.44(13)& 1.8e6\\%
  7 & -0.55(16) & 2.0e6 \\%
  8a & -0.54(16) & 1.9e6\\%
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 \caption[$\beta$ results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV]{The $\beta$ parameter results measured in this work for the 3d $Mg^{+}$ in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 57.45 eV.}
\label{table:120}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]